# TypeError: 'numpy.bool_' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean

I'm currently encounter a `TypeError: 'numpy.bool_' object is not iterable` without knowing why. I've verified each variables that I used. Do you have any idea why this error occurs? Here a simplified code of mine that you can use to play with :

```
import numpy as np


def rad_to_deg(x):
    deg = x*180/np.pi
    return deg

def flag_PA(x,bornes_test):  
    index_0_test = int(np.where(bornes_test==0)[0][0])
    for i in range(index_0_test):
        cond1 = any(bornes_test[i] <= x < bornes_test[i+1])
        cond2 = any(bornes_test[i]+180 <= x < bornes_test[i+1]+180)
        if np.logical_or(cond1,cond2)==True :
            flag_test=i 
    return flag_test


##################################### DATA READING ###########################

# Trouver les fichiers en Bande L et Bande N 


bornes_PA = np.linspace(-180,180,18+1)

lambda_fichier       = np.linspace(3E-6,11E-6)
u_coord_fichier      = np.linspace(1,40)
v_coord_fichier      = np.linspace(1,40)
baseline_fichier     = np.sqrt(np.array(u_coord_fichier)**2+np.array(v_coord_fichier)**2).tolist()
for l in range(len(lambda_fichier)):
    for b in range(len(baseline_fichier)):
        deg = rad_to_deg(np.arctan2(u_coord_fichier[b],v_coord_fichier[b]))
        result = int(flag_PA(deg,bornes_PA))
```

Here is the full error  :

```
  line 34, in <module>
    result = int(flag_PA(deg,bornes_PA))

  line 13, in flag_PA
    cond1 = any(bornes_test[i] <= x < bornes_test[i+1])
```

Comment: Before I even look at the question, I can tell you what `TypeError: 'numpy.bool_' object is not iterable` means. It means that you have tried to iterate over an instance of `numpy.bool_`, which was likely an element in an array. Now the task is to figure out where and why this happened...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `any` tries to iterate over its argument.

The expression `bornes_test[i] <= x < bornes_test[i+1]` returns a scalar `numpy.bool_`, not an array.

Therefore `any(bornes_test[i] <= x < bornes_test[i+1])` is trying to iterate over a scalar, as stated by the error message.

It looks like you can just delete the `any` and obtain the intended result.

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you for this clarification. This was indeed, any which caused the problem.